# Djando, two models inherited from the same parent, one of them has a ForienKey to the other

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created two models inherited from the same parent. In one of them, I am trying to make a ForienKey to the other child. The following error appears

`TypeError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ReverseOneToOneDescriptor object at 0x7f2cdf0af9d0>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'`

user_model.py

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = MyUserManager()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        .
        .

class SupervisorUser(AppUser):
    objects = StudentManager()
    major = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     .
     .

class StudentUser(AppUser):
    objects = StudentManager()
    GPA = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(SupervisorUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     .
     .
```

I tried

```
supervisor = models.ForeignKey(AppUser.SupervisorUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but this error poped up `AttributeError: type object 'AppUser' has no attribute 'SupervisorUser'`

Comment: did you try specifying the relation with string: `app_name.SupervisorUser`?

Comment: Yes I did ---> AttributeError: type object 'AppUser' has no attribute 'SupervisorUser'

Comment: Can you share the managers code too? I did a simple test here and everything worked, so its something related with your custom managers.

Comment: @LuisFelipeKaufmanndasilva... 
The error message is: 
AttributeError: type object 'AppUser' has no attribute 'SupervisorUser'

Answer (score 0):

try to specify AppUser.supervisoruser (small letters for SupervisorUser)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).